# MessageBox in windows mobile 6.5

Tags: c#, mobile

I have a list view where-in I have to show an informational message box when selected item does not comply with properties.

However, In windows mobile 6.5 the message box with 'OK' accepts any click on the message box.
i.e. the user need not click on the 'OK' button.

This causes problem when the user clicks more than twice, the message box appears and disappears immediately.

Is there a way for me to control/restrict the click only to 'OK' button.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen that the boxes with only the *Ok* Button closes as soon as you touch the *messagebox* even if it is not on the button. It is a change from the previous version. But, *messageboxes* with two or more buttons should behave normally.

Hope this helps:)

Comment: If you really have to, you could always try to create a two button message box and delete on of them.